# Flutter Firebase User lost after closing app (device) or hot restart (simulator)

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, state, stream-builder

I am really desperate over this one:

I am using Firebase Auth with Streambuilder in my actual Flutter project. I have a weird authentication loss when performing the following:

1. Simulator: hot restart -> allways returning to the sign in screen (hot reload works just fine! When I am in the sign in screen after hot restart I just need to hot reload and the user is back and I am being taken to the landing screen).
2. device: closing the app -> same behavior as above -> sign in screen.

Now comes the weirdest part: A login with the same username & password is not possible in both cases... ??

Here is my main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>(
          create: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LanguageProvider>(
          create: (context) => LanguageProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(
        databaseBuilder: (_, userUID) => FirestoreDatabase(userUID: userUID),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

then follows the MyApp class (mainly for localization stuff):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key, this.databaseBuilder}) : super(key: key);

  final FirestoreDatabase Function(BuildContext context, String uid)
      databaseBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<LanguageProvider>(
      builder: (_, languageProviderRef, __) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'InventarQR',
          locale: languageProviderRef.appLocale,
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale('de', 'DE'),
            Locale('en', 'US'),
          ],
          //These delegates make sure that the localization data for the proper language is loaded
          localizationsDelegates: [
            //A class which loads the translations from JSON files
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            //Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets (means those default Material widget such as alert dialog icon text)
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            //Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            //Built-in localization of basic text for Cupertino widgets (means those default Material widget such as alert dialog icon text)
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
          ],
          //return a locale which will be used by the app
          localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
            //check if the current device locale is supported or not
            for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
              if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale?.languageCode ||
                  supportedLocale.countryCode == locale?.countryCode) {
                return supportedLocale;
              }
            }
            //if the locale from the mobile device is not supported yet,
            //user the first one from the list (in our case, that will be English)
            return supportedLocales.first;
          },
          theme: ThemeData(
              primaryColor: CONST_PRIMARY_COLOR, fontFamily: "AvenirNext"),
          home: LandingScreen(
            databaseBuilder: databaseBuilder,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and my Landing Page, which decides whether to go to the Home Screen or sign in screen:

```
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key key, this.databaseBuilder}) : super(key: key);

  final FirestoreDatabase Function(BuildContext context, String uid)
      databaseBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: auth.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          final User user = snapshot.data;
          print(auth.currentUser);
          if (user == null) {
            return SignInScreen();
          } else {
            return MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                Provider<FirestoreDatabase>(
                  create: (context) => databaseBuilder(context, user.uid),
                ),
              ],
              child: HomeScreen(),
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and finally my auth class:

```
class Auth extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User get currentUser => _firebaseAuth.currentUser;

  @override
  Stream<User> authStateChanges() => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return userCredential.user;
  }

...
```

What am I not seeing?

Thanks so much in advance!

Best,
Dom